# Как добавить сайта иконку в плитку opera

Tags: браузер, opera, иконки

Добрый день. 
Как добавить правильно иконку в плитку в браузере opera? Вот посмотрите как отображается Яндекс и как сайт gcore.lu
[image: Браузер Opera]

Comment: А это к программированию как относится?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что это как-то в HTML внедряется. Вот только как - не знаю )

Comment: https://maqentaer.com/devopera-static-backup/http/dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-speed-dial-enhancements/index.html на русском: https://habrahabr.ru/post/115705/